# Visual Basic - Write number that is bigger than number/numbers before it

Tags: vb.net, basic

I'm a Visual Basic newb and I have some task which bothers me for a long time. I don't know anyone who I can ask for tips, so I hope here would be some good people to give me at least a clue how to solve this.

Please note that I'm very new into this and please don't be rough on me. I need some example of "Write number that is bigger than number/numbers before it".
I'm not very skilled with English so I cant explain it very well or search for examples.

point is that I have 6 values and I need to test and write it into listbox, value witch  is bigger than all values before it (not after it and as many as there are)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private strClasses(5) As String


    Private Sub Buttonaddarray_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Buttonaddarray.Click
        clearlist()

        strClasses(0) = Val(InputBox("Unesite visinu prvog covjeka"))
        strClasses(1) = Val(InputBox("Unesite visinu drugog covjeka"))
        strClasses(2) = Val(InputBox("Unesite visinu treceg covjeka"))
        strClasses(3) = Val(InputBox("Unesite visinu cetvrtog covjeka"))
        strClasses(4) = Val(InputBox("Unesite visinu petog covjeka"))
        strClasses(5) = Val(InputBox("Unesite visinu sestog covjeka"))


        For i As Integer = 0 To strClasses.Length - 1
            listarray.Items.Add(strClasses(i))

        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub clearlist()
        listarray.Items.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Buttonsort_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Buttonsort.Click
        clearlist()

        Dim a As Integer = strClasses(0)
        Dim b As Integer = strClasses(1)
        Dim c As Integer = strClasses(2)
        Dim d As Integer = strClasses(3)
        Dim f As Integer = strClasses(4)
        Dim g As Integer = strClasses(5)



        listarray.Items.Add("Blagajnik vidi ljude sledećih visina")

        listarray.Items.Add(a)

        If b > a Then
            listarray.Items.Add(b)
        End If
        If c > a And c > b Then
            listarray.Items.Add(c)
        End If
        If d > a And d > b And d > c Then
            listarray.Items.Add(d)
        End If
        If f > a And f > b And f > c And f > d Then
            listarray.Items.Add(f)
        End If
        If g > a And g > b And g > c And g > d And g > f Then
            listarray.Items.Add(g)
        End If



    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: So, to be clear, are you saying that you have a set of numbers entered by the user and you want to sort them and display them in ascending order?

Comment: Not to sort them, just to show numbers which are greater then all numbers before it.
ex: if I type 1 2 1 5 6
program should show 1 2 5 6
if I type 10 5 6 9 11
program should show 10 11

I hope you understand me.

And than you for replying :)

Comment: Sounds like you want to keep the running highest value as you run through all your values.

Comment: Something like that. But I cant find anything useful online on my language and Im not sure how to type it on English :(

Comment: Ooooohhh dear God I just noticed that all my values are set to strClasses(0).
Now I see why its doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This should return the result you're looking for.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim strClasses(5) As Integer
    strClasses(0) = 1
    strClasses(1) = 2
    strClasses(2) = 1
    strClasses(3) = 5
    strClasses(4) = 6

    Debug.Print(maxOutArray(strClasses))

    strClasses(0) = 10
    strClasses(1) = 5
    strClasses(2) = 6
    strClasses(3) = 9
    strClasses(4) = 11

    Debug.Print(maxOutArray(strClasses))

End Sub

Private Function maxOutArray(values() As Integer) As String
    Dim currentHightest As Integer

    Dim returnVal As String = String.Empty

    For Each parseInt As Integer In values
        If parseInt > currentHightest Then
            currentHightest = parseInt
            returnVal = String.Concat(returnVal, " ", currentHightest)
        End If
    Next
    Return returnVal

End Function
```